# Animate Positioned Container between two separate widgets

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I built a solution that works to what I thought would be a simple problem, but it took me many hours to get this to work.  While my solution works, I wonder if I've over-engineered something that should be far simpler.

I'm trying to animate the movement of an underline bar between two different text widgets.  In the example solution I'm including the two text widgets are "Sign In" and "Sign Up".  My app is localized in multiple languages, so those words could be different based on locale.  My app also needs to be responsive (window/orientation changes).  I tried every variation of Stack, Positioned, Row, Column I could think of, but couldn't get it to work.

My end solution was to use an Overlay Animated Container Widget in combination with the GetX state management.  To get my solution below to work, you'll need to add `get: ^3.15.0` to your pubspec.yaml file.  This solution doesn't work with `setState((){})`.

I would love to know if there is a simpler/better solution to animating a PositionedContainer so that it's aligned to the position and size of two other widgets.  Keep in mind the need to support localization and responsiveness. Either way, maybe this can serve as an example usage of Overlays that's useful to others.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(OverlayApp());
}

class OverlayApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Overlay Test',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: OverlayHome(),
    );
  }
}

class OverlayHome extends StatelessWidget {
  var _isSignIn = true.obs;
  final _signinKey = GlobalKey();
  final _signupKey = GlobalKey();

  OverlayEntry _indicatorOverlayEntry;

  void _setIndicator() {
    _indicatorOverlayEntry?.remove();
    SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      _indicatorOverlayEntry = _overlayEntry();
      Overlay.of(_signinKey.currentContext).insert(_indicatorOverlayEntry);
    });
  }

  OverlayEntry _overlayEntry() {
    RenderBox signinRenderBox = _signinKey.currentContext.findRenderObject();
    RenderBox signupRenderBox = _signupKey.currentContext.findRenderObject();
    final signinWidgetPosition = signinRenderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
    final signupWidgetPosition = signupRenderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
    final signinWidgetSize = signinRenderBox.size;
    final signupWidgetSize = signupRenderBox.size;

    return OverlayEntry(
      builder: (context) => Stack(
        children: [
          Obx(
            () => AnimatedPositioned(
              duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
              curve: Curves.easeOutQuint,
              top: signinWidgetPosition.dy + signinWidgetSize.height,
              height: 3.0,
              left: (_isSignIn.value)
                  ? signinWidgetPosition.dx
                  : signupWidgetPosition.dx,
              width: (_isSignIn.value)
                  ? signinWidgetSize.width
                  : signupWidgetSize.width,
              child: Container(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: LayoutBuilder(
          builder: (context, constraints) {
            _setIndicator();
            return Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                SizedBox(height: 20),
                Text(
                  'Animated Overlay Test',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 30),
                Obx(
                  () => Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: [
                      FlatButton(
                        child: Text(
                          "Sign In",
                          key: _signinKey,
                          style: (_isSignIn.value)
                              ? TextStyle(
                                  color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                                  fontSize: 18,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)
                              : TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  fontSize: 18,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {
                          _isSignIn.value = true;
                        },
                      ),
                      FlatButton(
                        child: Text(
                          "Sign Up",
                          key: _signupKey,
                          style: (!_isSignIn.value)
                              ? TextStyle(
                                  color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                                  fontSize: 18,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)
                              : TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  fontSize: 18,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {
                          _isSignIn.value = false;
                        },
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "an underline bar between two different text widgets"? some image maybe?

Comment: Think of two states:  Signin and Signup.  The underline is positioned exactly under the word "Signin" during that state.  When the user clicks/taps on the word "Sign Up", the underline bar moves/animates from the word "Sign In" to the word "Sign Up".

Comment: In this case the underline is simply a rectangle container of height 3, and takes the width of either the text "Sign in" or "Sign up" (words could be different based on locale).

Comment: Thanks.  I did try CustomMultiChildLayout to no avail.  I would need to have a Row for the two text widgets, then that Row would get wrapped in a Column for the Container.  At that point, there was no way for me to animate the Container since the parent is the Column and not the Row with the text widgets.  I will look again though.  If you do find a way to make it work, please let me know.

Comment: Ok, went and looked again (I had to remind myself as I went down so many different paths to get this to work).  The issue is that I don't know the width of the text ("Sign In" or "Sign Out") until it's rendered (remember, text is localized) and therefore, I can't set the width of the Animated Container (the underline).  It's definitely possible I'm still missing something because it was indeed a promising path.  Thanks again for looking into this, I appreciate it.

Comment: in the code i posted one text is "short" and the other "looooooooooooong" and i do not really care whats its size as `layoutChild()` method returns the correct rendered size - see lines #21 & 24

Comment: Well, thanks for this.  I have it (mostly) working.  For some reason, I can't get the Animation Controller to respect duration (it's way too slow right now).  Then, I'll think through layout positioning for responsiveness.  But, I do think you gave me the "proper" way to do this rather than my overlay solution. Thanks again.  Once I get it all working an layout out (and the animation duration fixed), I'll post the final code.

Comment: I was able to get your solution to work correctly.  While I think your solution is technically more correct than mine, it ends up being far more complex.  The reason is the need to manually layout all the children rather than just count on the Row widget to do it for me.  Also, when attempting to combine the CustomMultiChildLayout (in my case a row of children) with a Column of many other items on screen, the complexity goes up even higher.  Thanks again for showing me this solution.  I'm sure it will come in handy.

Comment: ok, forget about `CustomMultiChildLayout` - i found much, much easier, simpler and elegant way, but i have no time to post it now though..

Comment: btw, you said that  *" This solution doesn't work with setState((){})"* - what do you mean by that? does the code from the answer below work with `setState` (whatever way you use it)?

Comment: I use GetX as my state management everywhere.  I tried to build a self-contained example and not have any external dependencies.  When I tried to use setState to manage the animation, the underline indicator wouldn't animate.  I didn't spend a lot of time trying to understand why, so I just posted it with the GetX dependency.

Answer (score -3):

you can use something, like this:

```
child: Column(
  children: [
    TwinRow(
      twins: [
        Text('short'),
        Text('looooooooooooooooooooong'),
      ],
    ),
    TwinRow(
      twins: [
        Text('a bit longer'),
        Text('even looooooooooooooooooooonger'),
      ],
      tabColor: Colors.red,
      tabThickness: 1.5,
    ),
    TwinRow(
      twins: [
        Text('Sign In'),
        Text('Sign Up'),
      ],
      onPressed: (i) => print('pressed $i'),
      tabColor: Colors.orange,
      tabThickness: 4.5,
    ),
  ],
),
```

the main idea is to use a `CustomPainter` that is driven by an `AnimationController`:

```
class TwinRow extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<Widget> twins;
  final Function(int) onPressed;
  final Color tabColor;
  final double tabThickness;
  const TwinRow({
    Key key,
    @required this.twins,
    this.onPressed,
    this.tabColor,
    this.tabThickness = 3.0,
  }) : assert(twins.length == 2), super(key: key);

  @override
  _TwinRowState createState() => _TwinRowState();
}

class _TwinRowState extends State<TwinRow> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  GlobalKey _rowKey = GlobalKey();
  AnimationController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(
      duration: kTabScrollDuration,
      vsync: this,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var tabColor = widget.tabColor ?? Theme.of(context).indicatorColor;
    return CustomPaint(
      painter: _TabPainter(_controller, _rowKey, tabColor, widget.tabThickness),
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: widget.tabThickness),
        child: Row(
          key: _rowKey,
          children: [
            FlatButton(onPressed: () => _handlePress(0.0, 0), child: widget.twins[0]),
            FlatButton(onPressed: () => _handlePress(1.0, 1), child: widget.twins[1]),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _handlePress(double target, int index) {
    _controller.animateTo(target, curve: Curves.ease);
    widget.onPressed?.call(index);
  }
}

class _TabPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final Animation<double> animation;
  final GlobalKey rowKey;
  final Color tabColor;
  final double tabThickness;

  _TabPainter(this.animation, this.rowKey, this.tabColor, this.tabThickness) : super(repaint: animation);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    var rects = (rowKey.currentContext.findRenderObject() as RenderFlex)
      .getChildrenAsList()
      .map((e) => (e.parentData as BoxParentData).offset & e.size);
    // print(rects);
    var rect = Rect.lerp(rects.elementAt(0), rects.elementAt(1), animation.value);

    canvas.drawRect(rect.bottomLeft & Size(rect.width, tabThickness), Paint()..color = tabColor);
    /// elevated version with some shadow:
    // var path = Path()..addRect(rect.bottomLeft & Size(rect.width, tabThickness));
    // canvas.drawShadow(path, Colors.black, 2, true);
    // canvas.drawPath(path, Paint()..color = tabColor);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) => true;
}
```

Comment: This is an interesting solution.  I built a new main.dart file to make the two different solutions equivalent and posted [here](https://github.com/martin-robert-fink/indicator/).  One problem I run into with your "painter" solution is that the underline indicator is positioned properly when run as a MacOS app, but it's positioned much lower (too low) in the iOS simulator build.  I'm not sure why that is.  BTW, thanks for working on this because it also reinforced that the problem I was trying to solve wasn't a trivial thing with an "easy" solution.  Hopefully others benefit from both solutions

Comment: BTW... not sure who down voted your solution, and without a comment, it's hard to know why it was down voted.

Comment: *"but it's positioned much lower (too low) in the iOS simulator build."* - interesting..., hmmm, add `debugPaintSizeEnabled = true / false` and post two screenshots somewhere - also add some colorful `Container`s above and below `TwinRow`

Comment: I put two screenshots [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/84u006p20b3ueb0/AAAjb-ig1knOkWbJoKGT5SmEa?dl=0)

Comment: seems it has some strange vertical padding on iOS, what about `Container(color: Colors.orange, child: FlatButton(onPressed: () => _handlePress(1.0, 1), child: widget.twins[1])),`? it will show the actual bounds of `FlatButton`, another way to show it is `debugPaintSizeEnabled = true` - but put `tabThickness` some bigger number, say 32 or something - 3 could be not visible

`

Comment: Setting a Container height on iOS fixes the issue.  See new images at same location.  Interesting how the behavior is different between iOS and MacOS (and Linux/Web).  Is this a bug that should be reported?

Comment: I checked DevTools for both iOS and MacOS.  in the iOS case, the incoming BoxConstraints for the FlatButton height is 36 and in the MacOS case it's 28.  Wonder why?

Comment: i think i found the reason: in your `MaterialApp > ThemeData` add `materialTapTargetSize:` and play with both `MaterialTapTargetSize` values, seems that on my linux / chrome targets it is `shrinkWrap` - setting it to `padded` gives the same effect you see on your iOS (`padded` docs say: Expands the minimum tap target size to 48px by 48px.)

Comment: The MaterialTapTargetSize did make a difference.  It brought the box constrains from 48 to 36 (height).  But, not to 28 which is what it was on Mac.  I did do an Android build to check things out and it behaves the same as iOS.  I think I'm going to let this problem go now.  Thanks for your help, it was quite a learning/fun experience.